# can't use Racket's better-monads library

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, monads

I'm trying to make use of Racket's better-monads library.
I have the following program :

```
(module bmonads racket
  (provide add)
  (require functional/better-monads)

  (define (add)
    (mlet* ((x 10)
            (y 11))
           (+ x y))))
```

When I try to load this file into the REPL(geiser), I get the following error message :

```
Welcome to Racket v5.3.4.
racket@> (require (file "bmonads.rkt"))
bmonads.rkt:4:11: functional/better-monads: standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  collection: "functional"
  in collection directories:
   /home/me/.racket/5.3.4/collects
   /usr/share/racket/collects
   /home/me/.emacs.d/geiser-0.5/scheme/racket/
  in: functional/better-monads
  context...:
  standard-module-name-resolver
   standard-module-name-resolver
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
racket@>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `better-monads` is part of the PLT package `functional.plt`, you will need to load it via PlaneT.

`(require (planet "better-monads.rkt" ("toups" "functional.plt" 1 1)))`

Specific documentation for loading the library: http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=functional.plt&owner=toups

General documentation on PlaneT: http://docs.racket-lang.org/planet/Using_PLaneT.html?q=planeT&q=monand